# Dimensional weight shipping UPS API Magento

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, shipping, shipping-methods

I am using UPS as shipping but want to calculate shipping charges on dimensional weight of package. Which UPS API can I use to calculate shipping based on height length and width?

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

From the developer API of UPS there's the "Rates API",

Reading from the guide there's the possibility to get all the available rates for a shipment based on dimension and destination,
check: https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit?loc=en_IT

> Rating Compare delivery services and shipping rates to determine the
> best option for your customers.